# Distributed load testing with JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to run the Jmeter Load test with master slave configuration. The connectivity between Master and Slave is working up and fine. But when i am triggering the remote test from master i am getting the following error.

I have made the Slave server (Jmeter-server.bat file) ON

Jmeter Log

```
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 10.101.43.14
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Tue Mar 27 12:26:45 BST 2018 (1522150005491)
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 10.101.43.14 basedir='.'
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {}
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 10.101.43.14
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started 
**2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,10.101.43.14)
2018/03/27 12:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,10.101.43.14)**
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any errors there, looking into the output it appears that slave engine started the test and it immediately finished. There could be several reasons:

1. Your test is very short, i.e. it has only one sampler. If this is the case - check .jtl results file on JMeter Master host.
2. There is a problem with your test, the reasons could be in:

   - You use different JMeter versions on master and slave
   - You use different Java versions on master and slave
   - Your test uses a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which is not installed on the slave while present on master host

   Check `jmeter-server.log` file which should be generated in JMeter's "bin" folder on the slave machine for any suspicious entries, if you have problems with interpreting the log file - update your question with its contents. It would be good to take a look at `jmeter.log` file on master node as well.

In the mean time I would recommend getting familiarized with the next articles:

- [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)